# How to get rows from dataframe which satisfy certain conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains columns education and education-num. I want to know if every row in with X value in education corresponds to Y value in education-num.

I have been able to do this to some extent, being able to tell how many rows match or don't match this condition.

```py
def Educ_to_num(educ, educ_num, name, num):
  result = educ.str.contains(name) & (educ_num == num)
  matches = result[result == True].sum()
  print(str(matches))
  result_b = other['education'].str.contains(name)
  rows_name = result_b[result_b == True].sum()
  print(str(rows_name))
  if matches == rows_name:
    return name + ' equals ' + str(num);
  else:
    return name + ' does not equal ' + str(num);
```

I would call the function like this:

```
Educ_to_num(other['education'].dropna(), other['education-num'].dropna(), 'Masters', 14.0)
```

I have also tried to get the number which don't satisfy the criteria:

```
mom = other['education'].str.contains('HS-grad')[other['education-num'] != 9.0]
mom[mom == True].sum()
```

But I can't figure out how to display the rows where for instance 'education' is 'HS-grad' but the 'education-num' doesn't correspond to expected value 9.0. I want to display these rows to see what the problem is in my data. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to find rows where education='HS-grad' AND education-num != 9 ?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry if that is unclear, I will edit my question.

Comment: Thanks, please check if my query is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter by multiple columns, you could do -

```py
other[(other['education'] == 'Masters') & (other['education-num'] == 14)].dropna()
```

For your second case, the code would be -

```py
mom = other[(other['education'] == 'HS-grad') & (other['education-num'] != 9)].dropna()
```